# Computational Complexity of Densely Connected 3SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Given a $3SAT$ instance with $V$ variables, where each variable occurs 4 times: twice as positive and twice as negative literal. This problem is $NP-Complete$.

Now, given an additional constraint that this $3SAT$ instance is 'densely connected' as follows: For any integer $k$, if we select any $2^k-1$ clauses, the number of remaining clauses that share 1 or more variable with these $2^k$ clauses is at least $2^k+1$.

What is the computational complexity of this densely connected $3SAT$ variant?

Comment: It seems weird that the condition must hold for all $k$, since it is clearly false when $k > \log m$, where $m$ is the number of clauses. Is $k$ a single number that is part of the instance? If $k$ a fixed constant that is part of the problem (rather than given as input)?

Comment: Apologies, I should have explicitly mentioned that the constraint holds till the last step possible. As soon as $C-((2^k)-1)) < 2^k+1$ of course it won't hold. ($C$ is the number of clauses in the instance). Is that what you meant?